# Installing oracle 12c R2 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: oracle, ubuntu

Installing Oracle 12c Release 2 on Ubuntu fails because it is not a supported distribution. How can I install it anyway?

Answer (score 12):

Download the installation files and unzip them as usual.

Create the oracle, dba and oinstall users:

```
sudo groupadd oinstall
sudo groupadd dba
sudo useradd -g oinstall -G dba,oinstall -s /bin/bash -m -d /home/oracle oracle
```

Add the following parameters to /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576
fs.file-max = 6815744
kernel.shmall = 3355443
kernel.shmmax = 17179869184
kernel.shmmni = 4096

# semaphores: semmsl, semmns, semopm, semmni
kernel.sem = 250 32000 100 128
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 9000 65500
net.core.rmem_default=262144
net.core.rmem_max=4194304
net.core.wmem_default=262144
net.core.wmem_max=1048576
```

The above is for a 32GB machine. If you have a different amount then set:

- shmmax = (memory in bytes / 2)

Now install a set of packages needed for the install to complete. Start by updating your packages:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then install the following:

```
sudo apt install libc6-i386 \
gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 libstdc++6:i386 \
alien autoconf automake autotools-dev elfutils rpm rpm-common \
build-essential debhelper expat gawk gsfonts-x11 html2text sysstat \
unixodbc unixodbc-dev doxygen ksh openssh-server pax perl-doc rlwrap \
lsb lsb-core zlibc \
lib32z1-dev lib32ncurses5 libaio1 libaio-dev \
libelf-dev libodbcinstq4-1 libpth-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev \
libpthread-workqueue0 libpthread-workqueue-dev \
libtiff5-dev libzthread-dev libqt4-opengl:i386 libodbcinstq4-1:i386 \
libglu1-mesa:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxtst6

sudo apt-get install -s cabextract
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wimtools libwim-dev
sudo apt install -s libbz2-dev:i386
```

Create a number of soft links so that the installation can find the files it needs at the places it expects them to be:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/basename /bin/basename
sudo ln -s bin/bash /usr/bin/bash
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/rpm /bin/rpm
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/awk /bin/awk
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib64
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread_nonshared.a /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a
sudo ln -s /lib/lsb/init-functions /etc/init.d/functions
sudo ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

Now start the Oracle installer running under account "oracle", usually as follows:

```
xhost +
sudo su - oracle
cd /path/to/unzipped/files/database
./runInstaller
```

Install the database but do **not** create a database during the installation!

After a while the installation will give an error on linking. Leave the error message on-screen, then open a terminal and edit the file $ORACLE_HOME/bin/orald. Find, at the start, the part reading:

```
if [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" -o -n "$ORALD_USE_GCC" ] ; then
  exec gcc "$@"
  exit 1
fi
```

and change the gcc line to read:

```
exec gcc -no-pie "$@"
```

(the -no-pie option starts with a single dash).

Then copy the following script into a file, for instance /tmp/fixora:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change the path below to point to your installation
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/12cr2

sudo ln -s $ORACLE_HOME/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1 /usr/lib
sudo ln -s $ORACLE_HOME/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 /usr/lib

cp $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.bkp
cp $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.bkp

sed -i 's/\$(ORAPWD_LINKLINE)/\$(ORAPWD_LINKLINE) -lnnz12/' $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk
sed -i 's/\$(HSOTS_LINKLINE)/\$(HSOTS_LINKLINE) -lagtsh/' $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk
sed -i 's/\$(EXTPROC_LINKLINE)/\$(EXTPROC_LINKLINE) -lagtsh/' $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk
sed -i 's/\$(OPT) \$(HSOTSMAI)/\$(OPT) -Wl,--no-as-needed \$(HSOTSMAI)/' $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk
sed -i 's/\$(OPT) \$(HSDEPMAI)/\$(OPT) -Wl,--no-as-needed \$(HSDEPMAI)/' $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk
sed -i 's/\$(OPT) \$(EXTPMAI)/\$(OPT) -Wl,--no-as-needed \$(EXTPMAI)/' $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk
sed -i 's/^\(TNSLSNR_LINKLINE.*\$(TNSLSNR_OFILES)\) \(\$(LINKTTLIBS)\)/\1 -Wl,--no-as-needed \2/g' $ORACLE_HOME/network/lib/env_network.mk
sed -i 's/\$(SPOBJS) \$(LLIBSERVER)/\$(SPOBJS) -Wl,--no-as-needed \$(LLIBSERVER)/' $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk
sed -i 's/\$(S0MAIN) \$(SSKFEDED)/\$(S0MAIN) -Wl,--no-as-needed \$(SSKFEDED)/' $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk
sed -i 's/\$(S0MAIN) \$(SSKFODED)/\$(S0MAIN) -Wl,--no-as-needed \$(SSKFODED)/' $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk
sed -i 's/\$(S0MAIN) \$(SSKFNDGED)/\$(S0MAIN) -Wl,--no-as-needed \$(SSKFNDGED)/' $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk
sed -i 's/\$(S0MAIN) \$(SSKFMUED)/\$(S0MAIN) -Wl,--no-as-needed \$(SSKFMUED)/' $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk
sed -i 's/^\(ORACLE_LINKLINE.*\$(ORACLE_LINKER)\) \($(PL_FLAGS)\)/\1 -Wl,--no-as-needed \2/g' $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk
sed -i 's/\$LD \$LD_RUNTIME/$LD -Wl,--no-as-needed \$LD_RUNTIME/' $ORACLE_HOME/bin/genorasdksh
sed -i 's/\$(GETCRSHOME_OBJ1) \$(OCRLIBS_DEFAULT)/\$(GETCRSHOME_OBJ1) -Wl,--no-as-needed \$(OCRLIBS_DEFAULT)/' $ORACLE_HOME/srvm/lib/env_srvm.mk

sed -i 's/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--disable-new-dtags/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed,--disable-new-dtags/' $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk
sed -i 's/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--disable-new-dtags/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed,--disable-new-dtags/' $ORACLE_HOME/crs/lib/env_has.mk;
sed -i 's/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--disable-new-dtags/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed,--disable-new-dtags/' $ORACLE_HOME/odbc/lib/env_odbc.mk;
sed -i 's/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--disable-new-dtags/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed,--disable-new-dtags/' $ORACLE_HOME/precomp/lib/env_precomp.mk;
sed -i 's/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--disable-new-dtags/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed,--disable-new-dtags/' $ORACLE_HOME/srvm/lib/env_srvm.mk;
sed -i 's/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--disable-new-dtags/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed,--disable-new-dtags/' $ORACLE_HOME/network/lib/env_network.mk;
sed -i 's/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--disable-new-dtags/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed,--disable-new-dtags/' $ORACLE_HOME/ldap/lib/env_ldap.mk;
sed -i 's/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--disable-new-dtags/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed,--disable-new-dtags/' $ORACLE_HOME/ord/im/lib/env_ordim.mk;
sed -i 's/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--disable-new-dtags/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed,--disable-new-dtags/' $ORACLE_HOME/plsql/lib/env_plsql.mk;
sed -i 's/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--disable-new-dtags/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed,--disable-new-dtags/' $ORACLE_HOME/ctx/lib/env_ctx.mk;
sed -i 's/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--disable-new-dtags/LDDISABLENEWDTAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed,--disable-new-dtags/' $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/lib/env_sqlplus.mk;
```

Change the ORACLE_HOME line in the script to point to your installation directory for Oracle. Make the script executable and run it as the oracle user:

```
chmod a+x /tmp/fixora
sudo su - oracle
/tmp/fixora
```

Now return to the installer and press the "retry" button on the error dialog. The installation should now finish without further issues.

The resulting installation does not work, however: creating a database will hang in the "startup mount" command, with an oracle BEQ process deadlocked inside localtime. To fix that do the following, again as the user oracle:

```
cd $ORACLE_HOME/lib/stubs
rm libc*
cd ../../bin
./relink all
```

After the relink creating a database should work; you can create one using:

```
dbca -silent -createDatabase \
-templateName General_Purpose.dbc \
-gdbname $DBNAME -sid $DBNAME -responseFile NO_VALUE \
-characterSet AL32UTF8 \
-sysPassword REPLACE_WITH_PASSWORD \
-systemPassword REPLACE_WITH_PASSWORD \
-createAsContainerDatabase false \
-databaseType MULTIPURPOSE \
-automaticMemoryManagement false \
-totalMemory 2048 \
-storageType FS \
-datafileDestination "/opt/oracle/oradata/" \
-redoLogFileSize 500 \
-emConfiguration NONE \
-ignorePreReqs
```

Comment: I did this today on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and the linking during installation works fine following your instructions. So apparently this was fixed.

Comment: In case cannot install some packages run "sudo add-apt-repository universe" and "sudo apt-get update". Also if you can't I install the libstdc++6:i386 see this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/why-can-t-i-install-the-libstdc-6-i386-library-on-my-x64-ubuntu-droplet

Comment: Btw, you are missing sudo in ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh

Comment: Had to add before running installer $ sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386
and than

$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libxtst6

Comment: Thank you, this was great, but there were a couple of small problems I needed to correct to make this work. First, the correct binary location is at: "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/orald", not "lib". Second, I had to remove the '$' on "export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/12cr2".

Comment: I haven't received any installation linking error. Should I just proceed with installation?

Comment: If you did not have linking errors just continue, and see if your create database works. But if that hangs then you should try from the steps I wrote down. Good luck!

Comment: +1! That was really helpful - thank you. Combined with the information from [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwW4kl1E8GU) and the old [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DataBase/Oracle) I managed to successfully install 12.2 on my debian laptop ([MX Linux 18.3](https://mxlinux.org/) to be precise).

Answer (score 0):

Check that `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/oradism` belong to root and as setuid enabled:

```
-rwsr-x--- 1 root dba 95844 may 24  2018 $ORACLE_HOME/bin/oradism
```

Comment: While it is important that oradism indeed has the above owner and setuid this solves another problem than the one referred to in this question. So it might be good to also add what goes wrong if oradism has incorrect permissions, i.e. what kind of error messages you get.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the linking issue in ubuntu 18.04.
One pop up opened showing some linking error. I kept the popup open and after performing the below steps I clicked retry.

I checked the install log file and found it is not able to find few libraries.

INFO:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libpthread_nonshared.a

Then I ran :

## locate libpthread_nonshared

It showed my some directory where the same file was present. But oracle installer was looking for those files in /usr/lib64 folder.

So I created the soft links for those files using below command.

## cd /usr/lib64; ln -s /usr/lib/....../* /usr/lib64/

Then clicked on retry button.